# Python Exception during conversion from pdf to image

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, wand

In my

In the code snipped below I try to convert a pdf to images with Python Wand.
On my Local machine the code works.

```
file = request.files['file']
if file.filename == '':
       app.logger.error('Abort Request: Got Empty File')
       return api_feedback(2, 500, 'Abort Request, got empty file.')
if file and allowed_file(file.filename, 'pdf_to_image'):
    app.logger.info('Got allowed file type and got correct image and output')
unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
filename = unique_id + '.pdf'
file.save('/tmp/' + filename)
im = Image(filename='/tmp/' + filename, resolution=200)
for i, page in enumerate(im.sequence):
            with Image(page) as page_image:
                page_image.alpha_channel = False
                new_name = '%s-%s.png' % (unique_id, i)
                with StorageFactory.create(output) as storage:
                    output_file = new_name
                    storage.write_to(output_file, page_image)
```

If i run the code on my server I get the following error:

```
 DelegateError: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/dc53ce20-a14c-47b9-   
 9129-341b051a3676.pdf': No such file or directory @ 
 error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677

`2016-07-05 13:35:17,085 ERROR: Exception on / [POST] [in /opt//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1423]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    im = Image(filename='/tmp/' + filename, resolution=200)
  File "/opt/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2744, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution)
  File "/opt/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
DelegateError: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/160cc23f-3842-40dc-a440-3eeee8c6c5fe.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677
2016-07-05 13:35:17,086 ERROR: Internal Error details: [in ./app/__init__.py:40]
2016-07-05 13:35:17,086 ERROR: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/160cc23f-3842-40dc-a440-3eeee8c6c5fe.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677 [in ./app/__init__.py:41] `
```

Comment: Does Python say which line the error is on? Also are you sure a PDF called `dc53ce20-a14c-47b9-9129-341b051a3676.pdf` exists?

Comment: Yes the file exists. In line 3 in the snippet I save it to the /tmp directory. And with ls i see the file in the tmp directory. I added the error in the question

Comment: Where/how is `file` defined?

Comment: I added the code snippet in the question. File comes from a post request

Comment: Have you tried saving to a different directory than tmp like the Desktop?

Comment: @BennetLeff Yes i tried to upload it to the project directory. 
it works on my localhost but not on the server. If i run convert in the terminal on the server it works.

Comment: Is it possible you don't have write privileges on your server. Can you run the script as admin?